# Average Degree of a Random Geometric Graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

A set of $N$ points are distributed randomly on a unit square with uniform distribution. Two points $\mathbf{p}_i$ and $\mathbf{p}_j$ are said to be connected if $\|\mathbf{p}_i - \mathbf{p}_j\| \leq \delta$, where $0 < \delta < \sqrt2$.

What is the expected average degree ($2M/N$) of this graph?

Comment: Answer: $(N-1)p(\delta)$ where $p(\delta)=P(\|X-Y\|\leqslant\delta)$ for some i.i.d. $X$ and $Y$ uniformly distributed in the square. Awkward formulas for $p(\delta)$ might exist, did you search for them?

Comment: Just a question about the above comment.  I see that comes from counting the expected number of edges as ${N \choose 2}p(\delta)$.  But does that work even if the probability of having an edge between say $x$ and $y$ is affected by some other vertex $z$.  I mean, $p(xy \in E)$ seems different than $p(xy \in E | xz, yz \in E)$.

Comment: @Did This looks like the right forumla: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareLinePicking.html Thanks for your help.

Comment: @manuellafond You are asking a deeper question that it may look like. The reason why "this wotks" is that *expectation is linear*, that is, that E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y) even when X and Y are not independent.

Comment: @MGA Good search. Well, $p(\delta)$ is not so bad after all...

Comment: @Did Ah thank you, I just read about linearity of expectation and it all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The paper "Small-Worlds: Strong Clustering in Wireless Networks"  (http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1063.pdf) is indicating empirically that the average node degree $<k>$ is (or can be approximated by) $\frac{\Pi  r^2  n}{l^2}$ whereby two nodes are connected if they are within range $r$, $n$ is number of nodes, $l$ length of square.