# Expression of the thresold with expected degree in a Random Geometric Graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory

$n$ points ($P_i$) are distributed uniformly on the surface of an unit radius sphere.
2 points are interconnected if the distance between them is $\le r$ (thresold).
We call the degree of point $i$ ($d_i$) the number of edge (interconnexion between 2 points) coming from that point.
The expected average of degrees for all the points is $d$.
What is the formula for $r$ to get an average degree close to $d$?

I found a solution for this problem for an unit square here : [Average Degree of a Random Geometric Graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796746/average-degree-of-a-random-geometric-graph)

It is described there that the expected average is $(N−1)p(\delta)$ where $p(\delta)=P(\|X-Y\|\leqslant\delta)$ for some i.i.d. $X$ and $Y$ uniformly distributed in the square.

The expression of $p(δ)$ is discussed here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareLinePicking.html

I think that my problem is similar but here the problem is to find the average distance between two points picked in the surface of a sphere.

I found one demonstration here : http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0004021 (page 5 & 6)
Is it the expression of the probability $p(\delta)$ for a sphere with uniform distribution of points?

Comment: Are your distances calculated "through" or "around" the sphere?

Comment: I think that the distance is calculated "around" the sphere.

Comment: Is the sphere meant to have curvature? Or is it like the surface of the torus, and you consider the toroidal metric?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphereLinePicking.html.

Set $P_1=(0,0,1)$

Then $P_2=(\sqrt{1-u^2}\cos\theta,\sqrt{1-u^2}\sin\theta,u)$

From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalDistance.html

$l=\cos^{-1}(P_1.P_2)=\cos^{-1}u$

This is an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution with $a=-1$ and $b=1$ and has a probability density function of:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{(1+x)(1-x)}}$$

And a cummulative distribution function of:

$$F(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin\frac{x+1}{2}$$

Can you continue from there?

Comment: Ok. I'll look at this. I'll tell you my progress.

Comment: Is the $x$ in the density function and in the cumulative distribution function the distance between two points in the sphere?

Comment: Yes X is the distance

Comment: Should I use the cumulative distribution function to calculate $p(\delta)$?

Comment: Yes...........,

Comment: So the expression of $p(\delta)$ should be $p(\delta)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin\frac{\delta+1}{2}$?